# Postman HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, http, postman, payara

Помогите решить проблему. Любой URL ввожу и ошибка постоянно одна и та же. Сервер проекта запущен. На localhost:8080 заходит

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Payara Micro #badassfish - Error report</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 404 - Not Found</h1>
        <hr/>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>Not Found
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>The requested resource is not available.
        </p>
        <hr/>
        <h3>Payara Micro #badassfish</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: проект как "диплоили"?

Comment: mvn clean install --activate-profiles=debug    в консоле прописал    @not a Programmer

Comment: @not a Programmer   есть какие то идеи ?

Comment: Что такое Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish слышали? Вам нужно задиплоить проект на один из этих серверов.

Comment: Попробуйте дописать http или https в зависимости от того, что что нужно.